# Log summation with geometric progression

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Problem statement: Show that $\ln\left(x_{n}\right)<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3^{k}}$ where $x_{n}$ = $\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{2}}\right)...\left(1+\frac{1}{3^{n}}\right)$

I simplified RHS to be $\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}}{2}$
Then multiplied by 2, and not sure what to do now, after various attempts.
bump!

Comment: But what is $x_n$?

Comment: bump from Genghua Lv

Answer (score 2):

We have,
$$
\ln(x_n)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{3^k}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{3^k}\right).
$$
From the inequality, $\ln(1+x)<x,\forall x>0$, we get,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{3^k}\right)<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{3^k}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\ln(x_n)<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{3^k}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln\bigl((1+\frac{1}{3})(1+\frac{1}{3^2})…(1+\frac{1}{3^n})\bigr)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(1+\frac{1}{3^k})$, try to prove that $\forall k\in\{1,2,…,n\}$ the following inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\ln\bigl(1+\frac{1}{3^k}\bigr)<\frac{1}{3^k}
\end{equation}